# How to post data to custom API via Ajax on Synfusion Angular Scheduler

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I'm currently trying to figure out how to post data to my API when an event is created using the editor window. I use Ajax to retrieve content already as shown below;

```
const ajax: Ajax = new Ajax(
  "https://localhost:3486/api/CalendarEvents?StartDate=" + startDate + "&EndDate=" + endDate,
  "GET",
  true
);
ajax.send().then();
ajax.onSuccess = (data: string): void =>
{
  this.scheduler.eventSettings = {
    dataSource: JSON.parse(data).map((value, index) => ({
      id: index,
      Subject: value.title,
      StartTime: value.startDate,
      EndTime: value.startDate
    })),
    fields: {
    }
  };
};
ajax.onFailure = (): void  =>
{

};
```

Furthermore, how do I get the currently selected date range when the user changes the date on the scheduler via view or date navigation.

```
onActionComplete(args: ActionEventArgs): void {
    if (args.requestType == "dateNavigate") {
      // how to get current date range ?
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**
Found how to get the currently selected date range:

```
onActionComplete(args: ActionEventArgs): void {
    if (args.requestType === "viewNavigate" || args.requestType === "dateNavigate") {
      const currentDates: Date[] = this.scheduleObj.getCurrentViewDates();
      const startDate = currentDates[0];
      const endDate = currentDates[currentDates.length - 1];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have validated your reported query "How to post data to custom API via Ajax on Synfusion Angular Scheduler" and prepared sample with service for your reference.

```
app.component.ts:  
  myClickFunction(args: any): void {
    let schObj = (document.querySelector('.e-schedule') as any)
      .ej2_instances[0];
    const ajax = new Ajax('http://localhost:54738/Home/GetData', 'GET', false);
    ajax.onSuccess = (data: any) => {
      schObj.eventSettings.dataSource = JSON.parse(data);
    };
    ajax.send();
  }
  onBegin(args: any): void {
    if (args.requestType === 'eventCreate') {
      this.temp = true;
      let schObj = (document.querySelector('.e-schedule') as any)
        .ej2_instances[0];
      const ajax = new Ajax(
        'http://localhost:54738/Home/Insert',
        'POST',
        false
      );
      ajax.data = JSON.stringify(args.data[0]);
      ajax.onSuccess = (data: any) => {
        schObj.eventSettings.dataSource = JSON.parse(data);
      };
      ajax.send();
    } else if (args.requestType === 'eventChange') {
      let schObj = (document.querySelector('.e-schedule') as any)
        .ej2_instances[0];
      const ajax = new Ajax(
        'http://localhost:54738/Home/Update',
        'POST',
        false
      );
      ajax.data = JSON.stringify(args.data);
      ajax.onSuccess = (data: any) => {
        schObj.eventSettings.dataSource = JSON.parse(data);
      };
      ajax.send();
    }
  }
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-schedule-custom-adaptor?file=app.component.ts
Service: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/344913/ze/Service-285380590